# How do I test an application in Ubuntu, without affecting the system?

Tags: 14.04, virtualization, testing

I would like to know what is the best way to test application (packages). Because some packages may damage the system. How can do that, in Windows there is Sanboxies for such tests. In Ubuntu I don't know how to do it, maybe changing the home directory?

Comment: I would recomend installing VirtualBox and testing the application in VM.

Comment: Boot a live Ubuntu instance and run the program install.

Comment: thank you, am looking for a quickly solution, for example, to use a virtual machine (in ubuntu not in virtualBox) and i just need some commands to run it and install packages for test, or something like this

Answer (score 1):

Just fire up a container with its own copy of the OS, run your test, and blow it away when you are done.

[Here are the instructions.](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/getting-started-cli/)

They run at bare metal speed, are insanely fast and simple to create and destroy, and do not permanently steal system resources that they aren't using.